# Problems launch Serenity's test on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to launch my serenity-Cucumber tests on a Jenkins server. Actually I'm stuck with a simple error when it launch ChromeDriver :

**"IPv4 port not available. Exiting..."**

My failed tests are simple : goes to a special url and verify if the url is the one expected

I'm running on maven 1.9.9 - cucumber 1.9.5 - serenity 1.9.9 - chromedriver 2.40 - jenkins 2.19.1

I run my project with command "clean verify"
I tried to set a proxy but it didn t change anything - and I tried to change chromeDriver's port without results

Is there someone who has already face this problem ?

**Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 4013
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 9015
Only local connections are allowed.
IPv4 port not available. Exiting...**

Comment: Is there a selenium grid also involved?

Comment: no I don't think so

Comment: I think I saw the same error in other post today only.

Comment: looks like you are using IPv6.  Switch your networking to IPv4 and it should work.

Comment: You mean forcing serenity ? or forcing my jenkins server ? i tried to run my test with the option -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true but it didn t change ... Do you know another command or option to force IPv4 ?